# How to show only parents subpages of current page item in vertical menu?

Tags: php, hierarchical, wp-list-pages, menus, recursive

I just can't find a way to make it possible to show only current parent items down to current page item in a vertical menu the "wordpress way".

What I want to achieve is the following dynamic structure, if I visit Page 3.2.2.2:

Page 1 Page 2 **Page 3** Page 4

- Page 3.1
- **Page 3.2**

  - Page 3.2.1
  - **Page 3.2.2**

    - Page 3.2.2.1
    - **Page 3.2.2.2**

      - Page 3.2.2.2.1
      - Page 3.2.2.2.2
    - Page 3.2.2.3
  - Page 3.2.3
- Page 3.3
- Page 3.4
- Page 3.5

So, only submenus for **Page 3.2.2.2**'s parents and it's own (if it has a submenu) will be listed, even if Page 3.4 or Page 3.2.3 also has submenus.

Comment: I really want to thank you for this solution. Do you know if there is any new method of doing this, or are you still using this approach? Thanks again. - Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved it myself. Here is the solution:

In **functions.php**:

```
function show_all_children($parent_id, $post_id, $current_level)
{   
$top_parents    = array();
$top_parents    = get_post_ancestors($post_id);
$top_parents[]  = $post_id;

$children = get_posts(
    array(
      'post_type'       => 'page'
    , 'posts_per_page'  => -1
    , 'post_parent'     => $parent_id
    , 'order_by'        => 'title'
    , 'order'           => 'ASC'
));

if (empty($children)) return;

echo '<ul class="children level-'.$current_level.'-children">';

foreach ($children as $child)
{
echo '<li';
    if (in_array($child->ID, $top_parents))
    {
    echo ' class="current_page_item"';
    }
echo '>';

echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">';
echo apply_filters('the_title', $child->post_title);
echo '</a>';

    // now call the same function for child of this child
    if ($child->ID && (in_array($child->ID, $top_parents)))
    {
    show_all_children($child->ID, $post_id, $current_level+1);
    }

echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
}
```

In **sidebar.php**:

```
<?php
$parents_ids   = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
$top_parent_id = (count($parents_ids) > 0) ? $parents_ids[count($parents_ids)-1] : $post->ID;
show_all_children($top_parent_id, $post->ID, 1);
?>
```

Comment: this is fantastic! i've been searching for a solution that does this for ages! this works perfectly, and i can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet from WordPress Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#List_current_Page.2C_ancestors_of_current_page.2C_and_children_of_current_page

Comment: That code doesn't keep the parent's sibling pages. I want the whole menu list for each parent of the current page to be listed. But not the cousin's menus.

Comment: Seriously. Isn't this type of menu, among the most common? What a miss by Wordpress not made ​​this possible in a simple manner. So, that is, **no one** has a solution to this?

Comment: Then, iterate on the root pages. Find the current page's first ancestor (in this case it would be Page 3.2) and build an array with all the post->parent IDs, working backwards. It is more difficult to explain than actually do it. Hope it helps.