# wp_nav_menu - show children of current menu item only?

Tags: menus

I am trying to create a menu structure with a simple concept:

1. A horizontal, 1-level deep main menu
2. A vertical submenu, that contains children of the current main menu item (2 levels deep)

Of course, the submenu should be shown in the following cases:

1. Viewing the main menu item
2. Viewing a direct child of the main menu item
3. Viewing a descendant of the main menu item (3rd level)

Since I want to keep the menu clean, I need to show the 3rd level for the currently active 2nd level menu item only.

Basically, I want to achieve the same thing as described in this topic: [How to show only parents subpages of current page item in vertical menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/how-to-show-only-parents-subpages-of-current-page-item-in-vertical-menu) - **BUT, using wp_nav_menu()**

I would be happy to use filters or custom walkers if somebody could point me to a right direction.

The important thing here to notice is that since wp_nav_menu can contain also custom links or category links, the solution should work for all of those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way but i would go like this-

1) Hook into `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter. The function will recieve a list of all menu-items. These menu items will already have the information regarding current page or current page's ancestor(do a `var_dump` once)

2) From these menu items, unset all the menu items which are not supposed to be shown & return the rest

```
foreach(<loop all items>) {

    if(<this item's parent is current page or it's ancestor>)
        // this element should be displayed
    else
        // this element should be deleted, unset() it

}
```

3) Override the `walk` and/or `display_element` methods in the custom walker, by default the children are added inside the parent's `<li>` tag, but as-per my understanding of your HTML you'll need them seperate

Alternatively if you're already overriding the `walk` method but keeping most of it's code in the custom walker, you can create a custom filter for the 2nd step above. This would make that loop much easier since the items will be already sorted

Comment: I guess this should be the way to go. Ideally, I would extend the wp_nav_menu function with 2 new arguments: depth, level and childOf. Pretty much just like wp_list_pages.
The